# Nav2 odometry for Ackermann plugin

Tags: ros, ros2, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am following this [tutorial](https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/odom/setup_odom.html) to set the odom to my [truck_robot xacro](https://pastebin.com/LW9aCeMc)

Unfortunately, I was not able to see the \odom or \demo_odom topic published in my terminal. After issue "ros2 topic list" I just get:

```
/clock
/demo/imu
/joint_states
/parameter_events
/performance_metrics
/robot_description
/rosout
/tf
/tf_static
```

I am unsure if the **libgazebo_ros_ackermann_drive** I used is still unavailable to ROS2 (I think this might not be the issue).

For the simple wheeled robot configured in the tutorial, the **odom** was published (it used the **differential plugin instead**).

Can someone figure out the issue and assist me in getting the odometry topic published?
My xacro is correct and opened on rviz and the gazebo.
My [launch_file](https://pastebin.com/iTGDf9SA)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413847/nav2-odometry-for-ackermann-plugin/) by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2023-03-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2023-03-30**:
This doesn't seem directly related to Nav2, but instead your control / simulation plugins. You might want to change the question's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've resolved the issue, and it turned out to be simpler than I initially thought. The problem was due to incorrect joint name nomenclature and not calling the  tags before the plugin declaration. By correcting the joint names and properly including the  tags, the truck now moves as expected using the Ackermann plugin

The fixed snippet of code:

```
  <gazebo>

    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_ackermann_drive" filename="libgazebo_ros_ackermann_drive.so">
      <ros>
        <namespace>/demo</namespace>
        <parameter name="cmd_vel_topic" value="cmd_demo"/>
        <parameter name="odom_topic" value="odom_demo"/>
        <parameter name="distance_topic" value="distance_demo"/>
      </ros>

      <update_rate>100.0</update_rate>

      <!-- wheels -->
      <front_left_joint>front_left_wheel_joint</front_left_joint>
      <front_right_joint>front_right_wheel_joint</front_right_joint>
      <rear_left_joint>rear_second_left_wheel_joint</rear_left_joint>
      <rear_right_joint>rear_second_right_wheel_joint</rear_right_joint>

      <!-- steering joints -->
      <left_steering_joint>front_left_steer_joint</left_steering_joint>
      <right_steering_joint>front_right_steer_joint</right_steering_joint>

      <!-- Other parameters remain the same -->
      <max_steer>0.6458</max_steer>
      <max_steering_angle>7.85</max_steering_angle>
      <max_speed>20</max_speed>

      <!-- PID tuning -->
      <left_steering_pid_gain>1500 0 1</left_steering_pid_gain>
      <left_steering_i_range>0 0</left_steering_i_range>
      <right_steering_pid_gain>1500 0 1</right_steering_pid_gain>
      <right_steering_i_range>0 0</right_steering_i_range>
      <linear_velocity_pid_gain>1000 0 1</linear_velocity_pid_gain>
      <linear_velocity_i_range>0 0</linear_velocity_i_range>

      <!-- output -->
      <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
      <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
      <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>
      <publish_distance>true</publish_distance>

      <odometry_frame>odom_demo</odometry_frame>
      <robot_base_frame>chassis</robot_base_frame>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

[image: image description]

The result: https://youtu.be/Wf3rhqRSTKw

---

Originally posted by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) with karma: 266 on 2023-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this well-explained example.

I've tried your code though, and it all worked except for the ackermann plugin.

When i compare it with the [libgazebo_ros_ackermann_drive documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/ros2_packages/rolling/api/gazebo_plugins/generated/classgazebo__plugins_1_1GazeboRosAckermannDrive.html)

it seems like your code is missing the

> <steering_wheel_joint>steering_joint</steering_wheel_joint>

Do you know which joint in your shared urdf that might be?

Or, if anyone know which joint is the "steering joint" in general that would be great.

Thanks